# How to Change Part of URL With a Function Input in R?

Tags: r, api, url

Let's say we have a url in R like:

```
url <- 'http://google.com/maps'
```

And the objective is to change the 'maps' part of it. I'd like to write a function where basically I can just input something (e.g. 'maps', 'images'), etc., and the relevant part of the url will automatically change to reflect what I'm typing in.

Is there a way to do this in R, where part of the url can be changed by typing something into a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the part you type into a variable and paste this to the base URL:

```
base_url <- "http://google.com/"
your_extension <- "maps"

paste0(base_url, your_extension) 

[1] "http://google.com/maps"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to start with a fixed URL, use `sub` to replace the last part:

```r
sub("\\w+$", 'foo', url)  
# "http://google.com/foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname` to remove the last part of the URL and paste it with additional custom string.

```
change_url_part <- function(base_url, string) {
  paste(dirname(base_url), string, sep = '/')
}

change_url_part('http://google.com/maps', 'images')
#[1] "http://google.com/images"
```